# Error Running Amplify Push after Running Amplify Auth Update

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync, aws-amplify, aws-ios

I followed the instructions [here](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/ios/authentication) to add authentication for my iOS app. I first ran `amplify auth update`, followed through all the steps, and then ran `amplify push`. However, `amplify push` failed with the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/gluegun/build/index.js:13
    throw up;
    ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/yunfeiguo/Documents/programming/zhiyouios/amplify/#current-cloud-backend/api/zhiyou'
```

Any idea what might the issue be here?

Answer (score 2):

I did the following and it resolved my issues.

Follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/2068) and call amplify hosting add.

Then move the api and auth folders and their content from the backend folder to the #current-cloud-backend folder.

Then run amplify push.